# Scala BitSet implemented with Java BitSet, for use in Scala Enumerations to replace ValueSet

Tags: scala, wrapper, bitset

Due to a performance profiling hotspot detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632554/scala-enumeration-valueset-slow-replacement-based-on-java-bitset), I implemented my own `BitSet` using Java's `BitSet`.  This is intended to replace the `Enumeration.ValueSet`.  However, it's a bit awkward to use, primarily due to my likely misunderstanding of the relationships between the `Enumeration` class, `Enumeration` type and concrete `Enumeration` object.

In my enumeration objects, I have to have code like this:

```
type BitSet = alder.BitSet[this.type]
val empty = alder.BitSet[this.type]()
```

Elsewhere, I need to do things like this:

```
alder.BitSet.fromBitMask[SomeEnumeration.type](...)
```

For `mkString` I need to actually pass in the enumeration object itself.  **Is there any way to make this entire edifice a little more user-friendly?**

```
package alder

import scala.language.implicitConversions

class BitSet[E <: Enumeration](val bits: java.util.BitSet) {

  def isEmpty: Boolean = bits.isEmpty

  def nonEmpty: Boolean = !isEmpty

  override def hashCode = bits.hashCode

  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case that: BitSet[E] => this.bits equals that.bits
    case _ => false
  }

  def union(that: BitSet[E]): BitSet[E] = {
    var newBits = bits
    newBits.or(that.bits)
    new BitSet[E](newBits)
  }

  def |(that: BitSet[E]): BitSet[E] = union(that)

  def |(v: E#Value): BitSet[E] = union(BitSet(v))

  def intersection(that: BitSet[E]): BitSet[E] = {
    var newBits = bits
    newBits.and(that.bits)
    new BitSet(newBits)
  }

  def &(that: BitSet[E]): BitSet[E] = intersection(that)

  def &(v: E#Value): BitSet[E] = intersection(BitSet(v))

  def contains(v: E#Value): Boolean = bits.get(v.id)

  def containsAll(that: BitSet[E]): Boolean = intersection(that) == that

  def containsAny(that: BitSet[E]): Boolean = intersection(that).nonEmpty

  def toBitMask(): Array[Long] = bits.toLongArray

  def mkString(e: E, sep: String): String =
  {
    val vs = e.ValueSet.fromBitMask(toBitMask())
    vs.mkString(sep)
  }

}

object BitSet {

  def apply[E <: Enumeration](): BitSet[E] = new BitSet[E](new java.util.BitSet)

  def apply[E <: Enumeration](vs: E#Value*): BitSet[E] = {
    var bits = new java.util.BitSet
    for (v <- vs) {
      bits.set(v.id)
    }
    new BitSet[E](bits)
  }

  def fromBitMask[E <: Enumeration](mask: Array[Long]): BitSet[E] =
    new BitSet[E](java.util.BitSet.valueOf(mask))

}
```

Comment: This code review was originally part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632554/scala-enumeration-valueset-isempty-slow

Answer (score 8):

After studying your code for a good long while, I realized that the reason you haven't gotten an answer is that there isn't really much to say about your code. Well done!

I would recommend adding some thorough ScalaDoc though. It has been my experience that Scala library developers have far too much faith in the ability of library users to magically understand what they really meant. Examples are wonderful things.

Comment: Thanks, it all still seems pretty awkward to me though...

Answer (score 2):

In `union()`, you wrote `new Bitset[E](newBits)`, but in `intersection()`, you wrote `new BitSet(newBits)`.  Even if they work the same, consistency would be good.

You have functions like `union` and redundant symbolic operators like `|`.  I suggest that `a.union(b)` should mutate `a`, whereas `a | b` should return a new `BitSet`.

There are a few more operations that would be necessary for a useful bitset, such as `not` (a.k.a `flip`) and `xor`.  It would also be nice to be able to test whether a particular bit is set without having to call `toBitMask()`.  Compare your wrapper against `java.util.BitSet` to see what is missing.